# How can I get the daily costs using the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, cost-management

Is it possible to get the daily costs using the AWS CLI tool?

I am looking for an output similar to the information available via the Cost Explorer in the AWS Web Console. I need a simple way to quickly check the expenses in my AWS account for the last several days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to get the daily expenses for the last days using the `aws ce` subcommand:

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage \
 --time-period Start=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="-240 hours"),End=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") \
 --granularity=DAILY \
 --metrics BlendedCost \
 --query "ResultsByTime[].[TimePeriod.Start, Total.BlendedCost.[Amount][0], Total.BlendedCost.[Unit][0]]" \
 --output text
```

Output:

```
2021-07-11  1.9959926052    USD
2021-07-12  2.0098551581    USD
2021-07-13  1.9654925302    USD
2021-07-14  1.9829672821    USD
2021-07-15  1.996039161     USD
2021-07-16  2.0303596042    USD
2021-07-17  2.0193637439    USD
2021-07-18  2.0282529061    USD
2021-07-19  3.1817841617    USD
2021-07-20  5.0995626964    USD
```